# How to insert an object into a cell?

Tags: matlab, insert, cell-array

I googled but couldn't find anything although I think this a general need.
I use this function in Matlab to insert an object in to a cell:

```
function ce = insertInCell(ce,toInsert,idexx)
    ce = [ce(1:idexx-1,1); cellToInsert; ce(idexx:end,1);];
end
```

I think this function works like this:
**1st:** creates a new cell by copying ce(1:idexx-1,1)
**2nd:** adds cellToInsert to this new cell
**3nd:** copies and adds ce(idexx:end,1); to the new cell

and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this? I mean a function that just updates the indices of the elements (Or I'm wrong and this function is efficient?)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to insert `an object` or just `a new cell element` into the cell?

Comment: @memyself I want to insert sometimes a matrix and sometimes a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB does not expose pointers, therefore you can't just update the indices (pointers), unless you write a MEX file for that purpose.

There is a bug in your code: in code you refer to a variable `cellToInsert`, but in the function definition you have only `toInsert`.

Your code only works for vertical cell arrays. It does not work for horizontal cell arrays or n-dimensional cell arrays. For vertical cell arrays it works with the `toInsert` -> `cellToInsert` fix.

Bugfixed version:

```
function ce = insertInCell(ce,cellToInsert,idexx)
    ce = [ce(1:idexx-1); cellToInsert; ce(idexx:end) ];
end
```